# How to stretch an autocomplete input

Tags: html, css, jquery-select2

I am working with `SELECT2` and my autocomplete look like this

[image]

**myForm**

```
<form th:object="${field}" name="modal" method="post"
            th:action="@{/ecran/champ}">

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" name="exampleModal"
                role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ajouter un
                                field a l'ecran</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
    <div class="modal-body">


    <input th:value="${ecran.id}" type="hidden" id="idEcranField"
                                name="idEcranField" /> 
    <input value="" id="idFieldExiste"
                                type="hidden" name="idFieldExiste" /> 
    <label class=" mb-2">Choisir
                                un field existant</label>




    <div class="control-group">
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" id="existeField" >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selectionnée le
                                        champs</option>
    <option th:each="fields: ${listFields}"
                                        th:value="${fields.id}" th:data-jira="${fields.idJira}"
                                        th:data-type="${fields.type}"
                                        th:data-defaut="${fields.value}" th:text="${fields.nom}">

                                    </option>
                                </select>
                            </div>


    <label class="mt-2">ID Jira du field</label> 
    <input type="text"
                                id="idJiraInput" class="form-control mb-2" autocomplete="off"
                                disabled> 
    <label class="mt-2">Type du field</label> <select
                                class="typeField form-control " id="typeField">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selectionnée le
                                    type du field</option>
    <option value="text" disabled>text</option>
    <option value="Text Long" disabled>Text Long</option>
    <option value="Date" disabled>Date</option>
    <option value="Select Simple" disabled>Select Simple</option>
    <option value="Select Multiple" disabled>Select
                                    Multiple</option>
                            </select>



    <div id="defaultValue" class=" mt-2">
    <input id="tagsinput" class="form-control input-width"
                                    type="text" data-role="tagsinput" disabled>
                            </div>






                        </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**myCSS**

```
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" ; 
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" ; 

@import "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" ; 

@import "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" ; 
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" ; 
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" ;
```

When i inspected the code i found a span generated from `SELECT2` that have `width : auto`

How to make it look like other `form-control`.

Comment: Without the CSS we cannot answer this. Please provide a minimal example (if possible using the code snippet tool). Also note that your french is full of mistakes :)

Comment: @Yann39 ok for the CSS code also for your knowledge every word is checked and validated before send it to production it can be french spanich chinesse it will never pass to the production if it is full of mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [SELECT2 Appearance](https://select2.org/appearance) simply do the following :

```
<select class="select2" id="existeField" style="width: 100%">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting the entire form's html code can help here, but maybe you can verify if the class is the same as the other select's.